# Module parse failed The top-level-await experiment is not enabled

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, npm, openai-api

```
import { keyboard } from '@testing-library/user-event/dist/keyboard';
import { RequiredError } from 'openai/dist/base'
import React from 'react'
import { Component } from 'react'
import { Container, Form, Button, Card } from 'react-bootstrap'

const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");

class ProductDescription extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            heading: 'The response from the AI will be shown here',
            response: '...... await the response'
        }
    }

    onFormSubmit = e => {
        // start by prevening the default
        e.preventDefault()

        const formData = new FormData(e.target),
            formDataObj = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries())
        console.log(formDataObj.productName)
        // OPENAI
        this.setState({
            heading: `AI product description suggestions for: ${formDataObj.productName}`,
            response: 'the response from OpenAI api will be shown here'
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Container>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <h1>generate product descriptions</h1>
                    <br />
                    <h4>generate product descriptions for any types of products, simply enter the name and productdescriptions to the card</h4>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <Form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
                        <Form.Group className='mb-3' controlId='formBasicEmail'>
                            <Form.Label>What products would you like to get a description for?</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type='text' name='productName' placeholder='Enter product name' />
                            <Form.Text className='text-muted'>Enter as much information as possible for more accurate descriptions</Form.Text>
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Button variant="primary" size="lg" type="submit">Get AI suggestions</Button>
                    </Form>
                    <br />
                    <br />

                    <Card>
                        <Card.Body>
                            <Card.Title><h1>{this.state.heading}</h1></Card.Title>
                            <hr />
                            <br />
                            <Card.Text>
                                <h4>
                                    {this.state.response}
                                </h4>
                            </Card.Text>
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                </Container>
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: 'your-api-key',
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

const response = await openai.createCompletion({
  model: "text-davinci-003",
  prompt: "generate product description explanation for the following product  apple iPhone 11\n\nThe Apple iPhone 11 is the latest version of Apple's iconic smartphone. Featuring a stunning new design, an A13 Bionic processor, and a dual rear-facing camera system, the iPhone 11's hardware is designed to give you an amazing mobile experience. With the ability to capture stunning 4K Ultra HD video, and a vibrant Retina HD display, the iPhone 11 provides unbeatable visual and audio quality. Additionally, iPhone 11 features an innovative range of features including Face ID, wireless charging, and a water-resistant body. With the power of iOS 13, you can safely and securely surf the web, communicate with ease, and stay connected with the people that matter most. With the Apple iPhone 11, you have the perfect combination of style and power.",
  temperature: 1,
  max_tokens: 200,
  top_p: 1,
  frequency_penalty: 0,
  presence_penalty: 0,
});
export default ProductDescription
```

I've used the npm package and having no idea why is it throwing an error just followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xxtu-bkSAB8) for some kind of help if we comment out the api section than all looks fine but can't do that I want to create a content generator tool in react.js with the help of this when we add some query into the input field and after pressing the submit button we get the detailed paragraph about the query like this [openai](https://beta.openai.com/playground?model=text-curie-001)